# Bar graph with qplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm try to plot a data frame with a bar graph with the following code:

```
df <- data.frame("Cat"=c("A", "B", "C"), "Var"=c(1,2,3))
qplot(Cat, Var, data=df, geom="bar")
```

However, I get the following error, and I can't seem to find a solution around this:

```
Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `?qplot`:

> It's great for allowing you to produce plots quickly, but I highly
>   recommend learning ggplot() as it makes it easier to create complex
>   graphics.

Try and learn `ggplot`. For your simple example:

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame("Cat"=c("A", "B", "C"), "Var"=c(1,2,3))
ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(Cat, Var))
```

[image]